# xCodeBuild command line/ code signing fail

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xcodebuild

I was using xcrun with Xcode 6.3 and I wasn't getting any issue.

```
<exec executable="xcrun" dir="${IOS_PROJECT_ROOT_SRC}" failonerror="true">
            <arg line="-sdk ${TARGET_SDK}" />
            <arg line="PackageApplication"/>
            <arg line="-v ${PROJECT_BUILD_LOCATION_SRC}/${IOS_APP_BUNDLE_NAME}.app" />
            <arg line="-o ${PACKAGE_DIR_SRC}/${APP_TARGET}.ipa" />
            <arg line="--sign '${CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY_SRC}'" />
            <arg line="--embed ${basedir}/${PROVISONING_PROFILE_SRC}" />
        </exec>
```

However, After I upgraded to xCode 7.3.1, the command started making issues on our app and after investigating, I read that I need to use xcodebuild command to create an archive and export a signed ipa file with our disruption cert.

I am using the following:

**First: Clean:**

```
<exec executable="xcodebuild" dir="${IOS_PROJECT_ROOT_SRC}" failonerror="true">
            <arg line="-project ${XCODE_PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj"/>
            <arg line="-alltargets clean"/>
        </exec>
```

**Second : Compile:**

```
<exec executable="xcodebuild" dir="${IOS_PROJECT_ROOT_SRC}"
            failonerror="true">
            <arg line="-project ${XCODE_PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj"/>
            <arg line="-alltargets" />
            <arg line="-sdk ${TARGET_SDK}" />
            <arg line="-arch armv7"/>
            <arg line="-configuration ${CONFIGURATION_NAME}" />
            <arg line="CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR='${PROJECT_BUILD_LOCATION_SRC}'"/>
            <arg value="clean"/>
            <arg value="build"/>
        </exec>
```

**Third: Create Archive:**

```
      <exec executable="xcodebuild" dir="${IOS_PROJECT_ROOT_SRC}" failonerror="true">
            <arg line="-scheme ${XCODE_PROJECT_NAME}" />
            <arg line="-sdk ${TARGET_SDK}" />
            <arg line="-archivePath ${IOS_PROJECT_ROOT_SRC}/${XCODE_PROJECT_NAME}.xcarchive" />
            <arg line="-configuration ${CONFIGURATION_NAME}" />
            <arg line="archive"/>
        </exec>
```

**Forth : Export the archive to signed IPA.**

```
         <exec executable="xcodebuild" dir="${IOS_PROJECT_ROOT_SRC}" failonerror="true">

            <arg line="-exportArchive"/>
            <arg line="-archivePath ${IOS_PROJECT_ROOT_SRC}/${XCODE_PROJECT_NAME}.xcarchive" />
            <arg line="-exportPath ${PACKAGE_DIR_SRC}" />
            <arg line="-exportFormat" />
            <arg line="IPA" />
            <arg line="PROVISIONING_PROFILE ${basedir}/${PROVISONING_PROFILE_SRC}" />

        </exec>
```

**However, I'm getting this error:**

```
 Codesign check fails : /var/folders/_y/069ykjxd3hv51j9l62flnq2m0000gn/T/12AEA489-05B5-4682-BE29-7527661382B4-14940-000038AD332AE345/BankMobile.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
     [exec] file missing: /private/var/folders/_y/069ykjxd3hv51j9l62flnq2m0000gn/T/12AEA489-05B5-4682-BE29-7527661382B4-14940-000038AD332AE345/BankMobile.app/archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent
```

I'm unable to create a signed IPA file, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

After three days of working on this I found the full solution which is the following:

**First**

In your Xcode project you need to remove `ResourcesRules.plist` from `Code Signing Resource Rules Path` and set the `other code signing flags` to `--no-strict`:

[image]

**Second:**

I removed all the scripts mentioned in the question and added the following:

```
    <property name="CONFIGURATION_NAME" value="Release"/>
    <property name="TARGET_SDK" value="iphoneos"/>
    <property name="PROVISONING_PROFILE_SRC" value='"Company Mobile In House Distribution"'/>

    <exec executable="xcodebuild" dir="${IOS_PROJECT_ROOT_SRC}" failonerror="true">

                <arg line="-scheme ${XCODE_PROJECT_NAME}" />
                <arg line="-sdk ${TARGET_SDK}" />
                <arg line="-archivePath ${IOS_PROJECT_ROOT_SRC}/${XCODE_PROJECT_NAME}.xcarchive" />
                <arg line="-configuration ${CONFIGURATION_NAME}" />
                <arg line="clean"/>
                <arg line="archive"/>

            </exec>

             <echo level="info">Exporting the Archive file ${XCODE_PROJECT_NAME}.xcarchive</echo>
             <exec executable="xcodebuild" dir="${IOS_PROJECT_ROOT_SRC}" failonerror="true">

                <arg line="-exportArchive"/>
                <arg line="-archivePath ${IOS_PROJECT_ROOT_SRC}/${XCODE_PROJECT_NAME}.xcarchive" />
                <arg line="-exportPath ${PACKAGE_DIR_SRC}/${APP_TARGET}.ipa" />
                <arg line="-exportProvisioningProfile ${PROVISONING_PROFILE_SRC}"/>
            </exec>
```

The tricky part is the value for `-exportProvisioningProfile`. This value is **NOT** the UUID of the provisioning profile.

It is the exact name appears in your xCode account under Provisioning Profiles, it **MUST** be surrounded by double quotes like "".

*[Review the `PROVISONING_PROFILE_SRC` value property carefully and update based on your own provisioning name as I added single quotes first then surrounded my provision name with double quotes]*:

[image]